# Where do I go to add paths(curves) in Blender 2.77?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I only see the option to create mesh. There's no "Add" tab as presented in most tutorial videos that used older versions of Blender. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably in mesh editing mode (which allows only to add meshes)

I presume you see that :

[image]

Go back in object mode :
[image]

So you have the add menus :
[image]